# What parts of HTTP response are compressed using HTTP compression?

Tags: http, http-compression

By reading resources on the internet I got the impression that only BODY of the response is compressed because you need to read the 'Content-Encoding' header before you can decompress anything and if that was compressed, browser would not be able to decompress it.

Later, I am reading about CRIME attack which states:

> CRIME <...> is a security exploit against secret web cookies

which implies that web cookies are also compressed, as otherwise, it would do no harm. But Cookies are sent in the headers, therefore some of the headers must be compressed.

I would like a clear answer on what parts of the HTTP response does the HTTP compression compress. Thanks.

**EDIT**:
My misunderstanding came from confusing CRIME and BREACH.

CRIME focuses on TLS compression, which compresses headers with the body, so the cookies are included.

BREACH focuses on HTTP level compression, which doesn't talk about Cookies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the entity body (i.e. payload or representation) is compressed, per the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.2)

> The "Content-Encoding" header field indicates what content codings
> have been applied to the representation, beyond those inherent in the
> media type, and thus what decoding mechanisms have to be applied in
> order to obtain data in the media type referenced by the Content-Type
> header field.  Content-Encoding is primarily used to allow a
> representation's data to be compressed without losing the identity of
> its underlying media type.

Comment: True, but you're citing an obsolete document.

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer. There is also transfer-encoding in HTTP/1.1, there is HTTP/2 header compression with HPACK, and there's TLS compression.

Comment: @Evert you are very welcome to provide a complete one :)